# Why var_dump a Doctrine Objects kill my Apache?

Tags: php, doctrine

I have a very strange problem, when I try to `var_dump` (or `print_r`) a Doctrine Object, my Apache responses with an empty blank page (200 OK header). I can `var_dump` a normal php var like:

```
$dummy = array("a" => 1, "b" =>2);
```

And it works fine. But I can't with any object from any Doctrine class, (like a result from `$connection->query()`, or an instance of a class from my object model with Doctrine).

Anybody knows why this happens?

Comment: This is the number one google result for "doctrine var_dump". Please can you accept the correct answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8646048/3408) not the "increase memory limit" one, which isn't really solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had that sometimes when trying to `print_r()` a self-referencing object - it gets into a loop and runs out of memory.  Possibly that's what's happening to you.

Try increasing the memory limit (`ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');`) and see if that fixes it.

Edit:   I don't think there's an actual fix for this - it's PHP's internal `var_dump` / `print_r` that don't limit depth on recursion (or don't do it properly, at least).  If you install the [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) extension, this can replace the built-in `var_dump` with a version that handles recursion much better.

Comment: you wont get helpful output, though, therefore better use the doctrine dump \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump() which is described in another answer

Comment: Increasing memory limit should never be considered a good answer. Its like recommending `chmod 777`.

Answer (score 51):

Lazy load proxies always contain an instance of Doctrine’s EntityManager and all its dependencies.

Therefore a `var_dump` will possibly dump a very large recursive structure which is impossible to render and read. You have to use `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump()` to restrict the dumping to a human readable level. Note that the default depth for this function is set to 2 (it's the second parameter)

Comment: A way to get around this, besides increasing the memory limit, would be to use [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and take advantage of its `xdebug.var_display_max_depth` to only dump to a certain depth of all that recursion.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `toArray` method of the `Doctrine_Record` class

```
var_dump($doctrine_record->toArray());
```

will only display the DB fields and avoid dumping the complete Doctrine internals (which contains self reference/recursion btw)

Answer (score 0):

You can use toArray if you are sure the object is an instance of Doctrine_Collection.
Xdebug does not help with doctrine records.

The way I suggest is implementing a custom recursive function to print object, that use Doctrine_Record::toArray() when neeeded

```
function var_dump_improved()
{
   foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
       if ($args instanceof Doctrine_Collection) {
          print_r($arg);
       } else if ( $arg instanceof Traversable || is_array($arg) ) {
          // do a foreach and recall var_dump_improved on subelements
       } else if (...) {
          // other types
       } 
   }   
}
```

Some recursive function to debug with max nesting levels are here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Look at the comments, look for "recursion"